# Simulink cannot propagate the variable-size mode from the output port 1

Tags: matlab, audio, simulink

I've created following model:
[image]

It takes an audio input and puts it though a denoising algorithm, then outputs the sound to the speakers. When de-attached without the `ASLA Audio Capture` and only using the Multimediafile(Without the switch) it works fine, but as soon as I set it up as shown on the image, I get following error:

```
Simulink cannot propagate the variable-size mode from the output port 1 of cryreg_v2/Short-Time FFT/x to the input port 1 of 'cryreg_v2/Short-Time FFT/Rebuffer. This input port expects a fixed-size mode. The variable-size mode originates from cryreg_v2/Manual Switch. Examine the configurations of cryreg_v2/Short-Time FFT/Rebuffer for one of the following scenarios: 1) the block does not support variable-size signals; 2) the block supports variable-size signals but needs to be configured for them.
```

My current suspession is that the Rebuffer doesn't take microphone input (As it's inconsistent and not fixed), so I need to create some sort of interval from the microphone the Rebuffer receives (Something I'm unsure on how to do).

How do I actually fix my error, and is my suspission correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buffer block does not support variable size inputs which is the reason for the error. When you disconnect audio capture block your input is not variable size which is why it works fine. You can verify this by removing your multimedia file block and switch and instead using only the audio capture.

You should fix this by avoiding variable size signal created at the output of Manual switch. Variable size signal is created because the inputs to the manual switch are of different sizes. To avoid variable size you can either set the output sizes from your two source blocks to the same or by introducing a buffer block before the manual switch block in one of its inputs to make the sizes same.